# Displaying divs using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm attempting to display the number of teams inside team-scroll-container, but I don't understand why it keeps on displaying 0. This is my first time working with Jsoup so I've only know the basics.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
public class FinalProject {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://overwatchleague.com/en-us/schedule?stage=regular_season&week=1&team=allteams").get();
        Elements body = doc.getElementsByClass("div#team-scroll-container");
        System.out.println(body.select("div").size());
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the loaded HTML document does not contain such an HTML element.

The element is created by the browser's JavaScript engine but Jsoup has no such an engine.

Open the URL in browser and press Ctrl-U to see the loaded HTML.